# Entity Framework Code First override onModelCreating() for TPT Inheritance Screwing Up Identity User and Role Models

Tags: entity-framework, linq, inheritance, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-migrations

I'm having problems extending the Fluent API to my inheritance classes.  I have taken the TPT (table per type) method and each type of the inheritance has a table.  I like table per type because the database is fully normalized and easy to maintain.  I am getting an error with overiding the `onModelCreating` method that this [article](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) instructed me to do.  It is losing the keys to the User and Roles Entities.

Base Abstract Class

```
namespace Home_Warranty.Models
{
    public abstract class Vendor
    {
        [Key]
        public int VendorID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int StreetNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string StreetName { get; set; }

        }
}
```

Inherited ServiceCompany Class from Vendor

```
namespace Home_Warranty.Models
 {
 [Table("ServiceCompanies")]
 public class ServiceCompany : Vendor
 {
    public string ACHClaim { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubContractorCompany> SubContractorCompanies{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ServiceCompanyUser> SubContractorUsers { get;set; }
    }
}
```

Where I added the entity models to enable the Fluent API with `onModelCreating()`

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceCompany>().ToTable("ServiceCompanies");

    }


    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error on my migration while updating database.  It definitely because of me overiding onCreateModel function.

```
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
Home_Warranty.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Home_Warranty.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

1. This doesn't seem like the best way to approach the issue.  Can I add this code somewhere else and get the actual results I want without screwing up the Users and Roles models?
2. I would like to be able to do something like this with the fluent API.

`var ListofServiceCompanies = db.ServiceCompanies.All()`

or should I just go through the Vendor Entity instead?

```
var ListofServiceCompanies = db.Vendor.SelectMany( Vendor is a ServiceComapny...etc)
```

I prefer to set up the entities correctly and make the code nice and easy to use.  Any insight or knowledge is appreciated.

Comment: If the base DbContext type has fluent mapping, you're not running it.  Your override of OnModelCreating is not chaining up to base.OnModelCreating.

Comment: Can you create an example with code that would chain up to base.OnModelCreating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All configurations for your identity entites are defined into `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`. So if you create your custom context `ApplicationDbContext` which derives from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` you need to call this line `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` before adding configurations for own entities like below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceCompany>().ToTable("ServiceCompanies");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  That fixed the issue with overide.  I'm still not able to access the ServiceCompany through the API under the dbcontext like below.  Any suggestions?                          
           `ListofServiceCompanies = db.ServiceCompanies.All()`

or should I just go through the Vendor Entity instead?

`var ListofServiceCompanies = db.Vendor.SelectMany(Where Vendor is a ServiceComapny...etc)`.  I would prefer the first over the second.

Comment: So you need to create another question for that new issue :)