# How do you fix a blocking/breaking issue on Entity Framework Model Builder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I feel like I can get things done, but, I am far from a good programmer and it is annoying me.

Using Entity Framework Core, I'm creating a project and just had to build a many to many relationship that required me to use the Fluent API to set the ends correctly.

The moment I did this, I wasn't able to compile the project or really do anything as the default identity framework that was on the project was interfering. The error was:

`The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined.`

I spent a good amount of time trying to debug this issue with no luck what so ever. After a quick search, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798317/identityuserloginstring-requires-a-primary-key-to-be-defined-error-while-addi) which whilst not exactly my issue (I have a single DbContext), the solution was to add the following:

`base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);`

The moment I did this, the project compiled and everything worked as expected.

So, my question really is - why? Can someone explain what is happening, why it's happening - but more importantly, it's great that Stack Overflow exists and I was able to get the answer, but, if you are a novice programmer, how would you understand and diagnose this issue?

I feel like whilst Stack Overflow is great for getting answers, I'm being lazy and I really want to learn why things are happening the way they are.

Comment: [This explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34013431/861716) should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is the answer to your why question. Not so sure about how you would know as a novice programmer, hopefully someone can provide more insight.

> All configurations for your identity entities are defined into IdentityDbContext. So if you create your custom context ApplicationDbContext which derives from IdentityDbContext you need to call this line base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); before adding configurations for own entities

[Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848968/entity-framework-code-first-override-onmodelcreating-for-tpt-inheritance-screw)